# iPython gives error for unexpected keyword argument 'inputhook'

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, ipython, miniconda

I installed Python 3 on a new Mac using Miniconda and have the following setup:

- macOS Catalina 10.15.1
- Conda 4.7.12
- Python 3.7.5
- iPython 7.9.0

When I try to run iPython in the terminal I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/g72/miniconda3/bin/ipython", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(start_ipython())
  File "/Users/g72/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 125, in start_ipython
    return launch_new_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/g72/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 663, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "</Users/g72/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/decorator.py:decorator-gen-113>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/Users/g72/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/g72/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 317, in initialize
    self.init_shell()
  File "/Users/g72/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 333, in init_shell
    ipython_dir=self.ipython_dir, user_ns=self.user_ns)
  File "/Users/g72/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/configurable.py", line 412, in instance
    inst = cls(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/g72/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/terminal/interactiveshell.py", line 464, in __init__
    self.init_prompt_toolkit_cli()
  File "/Users/g72/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/terminal/interactiveshell.py", line 296, in init_prompt_toolkit_cli
    **self._extra_prompt_options())
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'inputhook'

If you suspect this is an IPython bug, please report it at:
    https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues
or send an email to the mailing list at ipython-dev@python.org

You can print a more detailed traceback right now with "%tb", or use "%debug"
to interactively debug it.

Extra-detailed tracebacks for bug-reporting purposes can be enabled via:
    c.Application.verbose_crash=True
```

The error appears to be related to an `__init__()` method keyword argument 'inputhook'. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It may be this issue, or a new related since it should be fixed: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/11962

Downgrading prompt_toolkit worked for us: `conda install prompt_toolkit==2.0.10`

Edit: [kmario23's response (upgrade IPython installation) is now preferable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59188863/2956066) if possible!

Comment: This fixed the issue. Thank you for the help.

Comment: This fixed the issue now, in 2021. The alternative solution did not.

Answer (score 5):

This error occurs when using a version of IPython less than or equal to `7.9.0`. So, a better option would be to upgrade your IPython shell to the version `ipython-7.10.1`, which also solves the issue:

```
$ conda update ipython
```